# Style mapped views in a row react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I map over this.props.league to create these checkboxes
[image]

I want each checkbox selection item to be position in a row from left to right.

How do I do that when I have an indefinite amount of items?

This is my render:

```
        <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
              <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                }}
              >

                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 100
                    }}
                >

                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                        <Text>Leagues</Text>

                        {this.props.league === null ?'' : this.props.league.map(
                            (v, i) => {
                                return(
                                        <View 
                                            key={i}
                                            style={{
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Check
                                                checked={this.state.checked[i]}
                                                index={i}
                                                acronym={v.acronym}
                                                changeCheck={this.changeCheck}

                                            />
                                            <Text>{v.acronym}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                )
                            }
                        )}
                </View>
              </Modal>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(true);
                }}>
                <Text>Show Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
```

I tried a few different options, but none of them were able to position the two side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give parent view of check box style in order to show all items in a row

```
flexDirection: 'row'
```

And if you have an array so you can use flatlist to show as a list also it has option to show number of columns like if you want to show 2 checkbox per row, you can do as

```
<FlatList
           numColumns={2}
           ....
        />
```